# HTML : Render pages by clicking side navigation bar

Tags: html, css, uinavigationbar

This is something I have seen in many pages and I want to try it out.
What I want to do is that I want to have a left side navigation bar. On clicking each option, different results should be displayed. For example, the first option is say, details, and that is the default option. On entering the HTML page, I have this opened. On clicking send second option, a form is displayed in the right hand side, but without moving to a different page

Can someone tell me the name of this feature, and if possible where to find the code?

Comment: Single Page Web Application/Site

Comment: Is it possible to do this without involving a server

Comment: Generally, you have each view in its own element and then you show/hide those elements based on which button was clicked.